# Setting up Angular Firebase Hosting 404 page

Tags: angular, firebase, http-status-code-404, firebase-hosting, angular-router

Is it possible to override the angular router with firebase hosting redirects?

I have created a 404.html page to utilise the firebase 404 error handling.

I.e. adding this to the firebase.json rewrites":

```
[
    {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    },
    {
        "source": "/404",
        "destination": "/404.html"
    }
]
```

However the initial /index.html rewrite seems to prevent the 404 from working.

Or can this only be achieve with SSR?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Firebase Hosting configuration [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order):

> Within each of the redirects and rewrites attributes, Hosting applies the redirect or rewrite defined by the first rule with a URL pattern that matches the requested path. So, you need to deliberately order the rules within each of the redirects and rewrites attributes. Configured redirects still take precedence over rewrites.

It looks like your `**` wildcard rule for index.html is simply taking precedence over `/404` because it's listed first.  Try reversing their order.